# Excluding Condition if Parameter is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am fetching data using LINQ and Lambda with 2 conditions using this Query. Is it possible to write this logic without if else condition -

```
public List<Pallet> GetPallet(string palletID, string locationID)
{
    List<Pallet> data = new List<Pallet>();

    if (locationID != null)
        data = data.Where(x => x.PalletID == palletID && x.LocationID == locationID).ToList();
    else
        data = data.Where(x => x.PalletID == palletID).ToList();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Where is `location` coming from?  Should that have been `locationID`?

Comment: @RyanLundy Thanks corrected it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
public List<Pallet> GetPallet(string palletID, string locationID)
{
    List<Pallet> data = new List<Pallet>();
    data = data.Where(x => x.PalletID == palletID && (locationID == null || x.LocationID == locationID)).ToList();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't be an `&&` there instead of `||`?

Comment: No, because the substatement is correct if locationID is null or (it goes further when locationID is not null) if it equals to Pallet.LocationID

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of doing it with correct results:

```
data = data
.Where(x => x.PalletID == palletID)
.Where(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationID)? x.LocationID == locationID : true)
.ToList();
```

**NOTE:** The accepted answer will return the wrong result although the syntax is correct. It'll always compares the `LocationID` even if the `locationID` is null or empty. Note that, in case of `locationID == null` *we do not want to compare at all* (we don't want this: `x => x.LocationID == null`).